# Convert a logistic regression LBFGS model to POJO

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pojo, logistic-regression, h2o

Looking at H20, I was wondering if there is a way I can convert my Spark LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS() model to a POJO object. 
Currently, I ve been loading it with the LogisticRegressionModel.load() function but it takes about 40 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Right now H2O does not support export of Spark models into POJO. However, you can always use Sparkling Water: prepare data in Spark then call `val trainHF = h2oContext.asH2OFrame(sparkDataFrame)` and build GLM model on that data. H2O's GLM model can be easily exported to POJO.

Or with some effort you can extract information from Spark's GLM model and fill them into H2O's GLM model.